# What resistor values should I use for an optocoupler switching a MOSFET?

Tags: mosfet, opto-isolator

**Final Update**
[image]

I believe this to be correct now.  I also have simulated this circuit on the circuit here: [Link](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWEAmaAOSBmMA2ZAWNATnwWRzHxHyJCQUjoFMBaMMAKADMQijk6YAWEgB2AQiEhMwqLGQcA7uDETkaFeJA58jSBzBaRWzDg3GByBDighR4YQL1ykAEQBOAQwCWAOxAAagD2ADYALp4A5kwckZoCOowW2lp6HO68UpICRFJ4VEnwSrz82rrxZWnKuQkEmQnl%20tV55XwNjArNAoSMNdSE0un11HDD%20AMdcBwAJhX4OhWmGgLTTFyeAK7hxUKj81TJ%201A7yKNLi2bgxX26vVLnTcPnyeeYBlpkGkef1DK29phoOQAdBMLY9NA3F4-IFQhFohxdPY0LhqBgQCibAhxlc4pjBAJ8QhSlU7KY0Yx8T0rhlrIwjjhIF8FowGI9GcyqDhrNQWcUft9GbyCjtVMK5kQbI8%20tkShIpAowCiHGdLrt6SzpJAwEDsaJMLlKNYaCokk5oAULRwAMraHlHfU2I5JEDrEIAZyYtgUQVsIjq9MgfBQSWgUpQtjeQA)
Please feel free and tell me if anyone sees anything else wrong.

### [image: simulated]

**UPDATED Circuit:**

Based off of ElectronicsStudent suggestions.
[image]

---

**ORIGINAL BAD DESIGN:**
This is my circuit:

[image]

I think I have the MCU side of the circuit correct.  What I am having a hard time understanding is the value of R1.

From the datasheet, it looks like the maximum collector current is 50mA and the collector power dissipation is 150mW.

[image]

I used Ohm's law to figure out the value for R1:

```
I = 100mW/12v  (150mW was max so 100 used)
8.33mA for total power dissipation 

R1 = 12/8.33mA
1.44kΩ
```

**Question 1.**
I am curious if there is a voltage drop from the emitter to collector on the load side of the optoisolator.

**Question 2.**
MOSFETs are voltage-switched devices.  That being said does it matter that I am only sourcing 8.3mA into the gate to the source of the MOSFET?

**Question 3.**
I know MOSFET gates are like capacitors at first. I read that 1kΩ was a good "all around" value.  Is there a better way to figure this out?  I do possibly plan on doing some PWM (possibly to dim LEDS) as a load. (This might be answered in Q2.)

**Question 4.**

I have simulated a lamp as a load in this circuit.  I wanted to know if this looked like the right way to drive the load.

***References:***

[PC817 - Optoisolator Datasheet](http://www.soselectronic.cz/a_info/resource/d/pc817.pdf)

[FR120 - Power MOSFET Datasheet](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/2010051735_VBsemi-Elec-FR120N_C879050.pdf)

Comment: It won't work. Use a PMOS or move load to the drain.

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1:**

As the load-side is a "normal BJT" - there will be a  voltage drop of ~0.7V.

**Question 2:**

It wont affect the binary ON/OFF states of the FET. But the lower current you can provide, the slower the switching times are. The FET gate does form a RC-Filter.

**Question 3:**

Depends on what "Edge-Times" you need. The lower the resistance, the faster the switching happends for a given gate capacitance.

NOTE: You not only have to drive V+ on the Gate - you also have to consider how to drive the gate to GND potential.

**Question 4:**

No. Your circuit has some issues.

1. You want to use a N-FET as high-side switch without an additional gate-voltage rail (Vgate > Vload + Vth)
2. You are only driving one state of the gate "High-State". Your "off" state is not driven by the opto-coupler.
3. Your LED-Circuit seems rather strange.

**Alternative Circuit:**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNILLc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R1 limit the current thorugh the Opto-LED. R = U_Logic/I_Opto,Max

D3 serves as "Back-EMF supressor" in case the Load is inductive.

R3 limits the discharge current of the FET - required to "drive" "off" state.

R2||R3 is your "charge current" limiter of the FET. NOTE: R2 and R3 form a voltage divider. Your maximum gate voltage is determined by this divider.

C1 works to "stabelize" the input voltage a bit.

D2 serves as reverse voltage protection.

And the FET (any N-Chan fet) is used as switch.

**NOTE:**

Optocouplers do generally invert the logic as they are PNP-Types.

**EDIT 1:**

This schematic is the simplest version of your circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKIBT4.png)</sup>

This gives you VGs=12V/0.7V (Which should be okay for every N-FET to properly Turn On/Off)
Faster "Switch-Off" then "Switch-On"

No static current consumption for the FET/Opto in FET ON-State

Static current consumption for FET OFF-State. Led will be on, if FET is off.

Minimum component count - you can also get rid of C1 - but it is good were it is.

It uses a NPN-Type Optocoupler (As shown in your schematic)

**Caution:** In case of a "broken" or undriven opto (E.g Controller in reset) the circuit will flip the FET ON.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.
Question #1. 
I have edited the resistor value based off of a .7v drop.  I also calculated the voltage divider for R1 and now R3 (trying to match with your design).  It should be 10v now.

Question #4.
What is wrong with the LED circuit?  Specifically, the green led?

New Question:
Does the load placement look correct?  I was not planning on running inductive loads but whatever its more robust!

Thanks!

Comment: I forgot to include the updated design at the top of the question.  It's there now.  Thanks.

Comment: @ril3y #1 Looks good. Make !SURE! to use a PNP-Opto for this. Your current schematic shows an NPN. To use the current Opto change your Circuit as follows: Connect R1 to TP1 not Opto (4) . Connect Opto (4) to TP1. Connect Opto(3) to GND. You can get Rid of R3 if your FET survices 12V at the Gate - but you can keep it if you want 10V. You also can connect the Green LED in series with your opto LED input - this saves a single resistor. But Make sure the drop across the resistor and the green led are small enough to still drive the opto led then.

Comment: @ril3y #4 The old schematic used a voltage divider to drive a LED - rather uncommon. Just use a series resistor. #General: If your ESP is running from 3V3: Just use 1kOhm resistors for everything. Your LEDs will work, your Mosfet will Turn on with VGs=6V as well and you dont have to buy/manage different r-values.

Comment: @electronicsstudend,  I have updated my design to what I believe is correct. I have simulated it and I think it looks right?!  If you are still around plz let me know what you think.